# Would this work to add a check that a signature hasn't already been used?

Tags: security, code

I'm working on an exercise to learn smart contract security, and I am trying to add a check that a signature has not been previously used to this withdraw function. Below I put the original function as well as my attempt to add the check. What I did is create a hash of v, r, s to a mapping bytes to bool where the hash of v, r, s gets set to true once the signature is used.

Did I do it right? Below I put the original code and my revision of it at the very bottom.

Do I need to add "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32" to wrap the hash?

**Original Function:**

```
function withdrawTokensToL1(
        address to,
        uint256 amount,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) external {
        sendToL1(
            v,
            r,
            s,
            abi.encode(
                address(token),
                0, // value
                abi.encodeCall(
                    IERC20.transferFrom,
                    (address(vault), to, amount)
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

**My Revised Function to add a check for signature already used:**

```
function withdrawTokensToL1(
    address to,
    uint256 amount,
    uint8 v,
    bytes32 r,
    bytes32 s
) external {
  if(signatureToUsed[bytes(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(v, r, s))] = true) {
   revert BossBridge__SignatureAlreadyUsed();}
  bool success = sendToL1(
        v,
        r,
        s,
        abi.encode(
            address(token),
            0, // value
            abi.encodeCall(
                IERC20.transferFrom,
                (address(vault), to, amount)
            )
        )
    );
if(success) {
   signatureToUsed[bytes(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(v, r, s))] = true};
}
```